# Putting an image twice in a post affects the first one

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, markdown, images

This is an image at large size:

[image]

It doesn't look large, but I can assure you it is, because it's under this URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vajul.jpg

This is the same image again, but an added 's' before '.jpg' to make it smaller (in appose to an added 'l':

[image: Same Image]

Adding 's' to the second occurrence makes both of them small, even though the first one has a 'l'.  Why is this so?

Comment: Thanks, now I want to eat pizza.

Comment: C'mon guys, don't downvote PEBKAC *support* questions.

Comment: @Charles Oh, yeah, PEBKAC, I definitely know what that is.  Well, I hope that this PEBKAC issue gets fixed.

Comment: @Charles: This wasn't tagged as [tag:support], though, even if it probably should've been.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're overwriting the URL for the image:

```
![Image][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vajul.jpg

![Same Image][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vajus.jpg
```

Yes, you're writing a different URL *the first time*, but the second time you're defining a new URL to the identifier you used previously. Identifiers are all removed before Markdown starts getting processed, so `1` will end up being defined as whatever URL is set to it *last*, and *then* when it starts processing the images will be substituted in as that value. What you want to do is this:

```
![Image][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vajul.jpg

![Same Image][2]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vajus.jpg
```

Renders as:

> [image]
>
> [image: Same Image]

Comment: Beat me to it. +1. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, of course :)